# "The upload path does not appear to be valid". Codeigniter file upload not working

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

I have been stuck at this point for a long time and even after reading a number of posts, I haven't been able to find a solution.

I am making an interface for a quiz, and in the admin interface, I need to upload images to a folder and upload the image name to the database. I can handle to other things but the image upload is bugging me alot for a long time.

Please take a look at my code below.

### The Form

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/update_question'); ?>
<?php echo form_hidden('questionid', $question->level); ?>
<?php echo form_label('Comment', 'comment'); ?>
<div class="input">
<?php
    $arr_comment = array(
        'name'  => 'comment',
        'id'    => 'comment',
        'value' => $question->comment
        );
        echo form_textarea($arr_comment);
?>
</div>
<br/>
<?php echo form_label('Answer', 'answer'); ?>
<div class="input">
<?php
    $arr_answer = array(
            'name'  => 'answer',
            'id'    => 'answer',
            'size'  => '10000',
            'value' => $question->answer
    );
    echo form_input($arr_answer);
?>
</div>
<br/>
<?php echo form_label('Image', 'userfile'); ?>
<div class="input">
<?php
    $arr_image = array(
        'name'  => 'userfile',
        'id'  => 'userfile',
        'value' => ''
    );
    echo form_upload($arr_image);
?>
</div>
<br/>
<?php
$arr_button = array(
    'name'  => 'submit',
    'value' => 'Update Question',
    'class' => 'btn primary large'
    );
?>
<div class="input">
<?php echo form_submit($arr_button); ?>
</div>
<br/>
<?php
echo form_close();
if ($error != '')
    echo '<div class="alert-message error">'. $error.' </div>';
echo validation_errors();
?>
```

I have tried running a js which returns the filename in the upload box, and it does return it.

### The Controller

```
public function update_question() {
        $comment = $this->input->post('comment');
        $answer = $this->input->post('answer');

        echo var_dump(is_dir(base_url().'uploads/'));

        /*
         * Uploading image
         */
        $config['upload_path'] = base_url().'/uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_width'] = 0;
        $config['max_height'] = 0;
        $config['max_size'] = 0;
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                print_r($error);
        }
        else
        {
                $arr_image = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                print_r($arr_image);
        }

        $questionid = $this->input->post('questionid');
        $question_data = array(
            'comment'   => $comment,
            'answer'    => $answer
        );
        $this->load->model('adminmodel', 'admin');
        $question_data = $this->admin->update_question_data($questionid, $question_data);
        //redirect('admin/questions', 'location');
}
```

For my upload path, I have tried a number or combinations and the only one which returned a `TRUE` value was `var_dump(is_dir('/wamp/www/quark_edorado/uploads'));` but this also returned the same error.

I do not know where I am going wrong.

### Update

My directory structure is

```
/application/
/public/
    css/
    fonts/
    images/
    js/
/system/
/uploads/
```

I am operating a Windows machine and using WAMP. Does that make a difference?

Comment: have u tried by putting upload folder in application and public folder

Comment: @Hemant Putting the upload folder in application will make it inaccessible in terms of logic. And yes, I have tried to put it in public, but it didn't work.

Comment: Try removing `base_url()` from the $config['upload_path'].

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I was autoloading the library and somehow when I was trying to initialize the configuration by `$this->load->library('upload', $config);` it wouldn't do so.

Instead I put my config files in `config/upload.php`

The other method to do so would have been `$this->upload->initialize($config);`

Comment: Wahey, moving my config into the config/upload.php solved my problem!

Comment: Had same issue solved by: $this->upload->initialize($config);

Comment: @ViperTecPro hi i am getting he same error i have tried that solution but no use

Comment: for me, my upload folder was deleted by git revert =))

Comment: never mind that chmod 777 upload_folder in linux

Comment: Also had same issue, solved by: $this->upload->initialize($config);

Comment: that solved the problem for me

Answer (score 9):

Ok put your upload folder in on the original place as you show in your question and try this (give the relative path to your base_url)

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_width'] = 0;
$config['max_height'] = 0;
$config['max_size'] = 0;
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()) {
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    print_r($error);
} else {
    $arr_image = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    print_r($arr_image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())


try adding the file field name


if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
```

Comment: It's not making a difference because the error points out to my upload path and not the field.

Comment: ok open config/constants.php
    define('UPLOADS', APPPATH. 'uploads/');
$config['upload_path'] = UPLOADS;

Comment: No @Philip, I tried this and it is not working in CI3