# Why is my upload path invalid? (Codeigniter-Library)

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm creating a library as part of a project and one of the methods is a wrapper for the upload helper.

The method:

```
 public function upload(){

    echo "Doing upload";

    $config['upload_path']= RESOURCE_PATH . "Downloads";
    $config['allowed_types']='pdf|doc';
    $config['max_size']='10000';
    //echo $config['upload_path'];

    $this->CI->load->library('upload',$config);

    if(!$this->CI->upload->do_upload()){
        echo "Couldn't do the upload";
        echo $this->CI->upload->display_errors();
        echo $config['upload_path'];
    }
    else{
        echo "Could do the upload";
    }
}
```

I've checked the directory permissions of the Downloads folder and that it exists but I'm getting the following error: **"The upload path does not appear to be valid."**

How do I resolve this issue?

**EDIT:: I created a symlink so my directory strucutre really looks like:**

```
 www -> /home/user/Dropbox/www/appname
```

Note about variables used:

```
$this->CI = &get_instance(); // Defined in custom library class 
define('RESOURCE_PATH', APPPATH . 'views/resources/'); // Defined in constants.php
```

Comment: What do you get when you `echo RESOURCE_PATH . "Downloads";`?

Comment: I get application/views/resources/Downloads

Comment: You will want to use an absolute path. It needs to be c:\folder\file.ext (or unix: /home/folder/file.ext).

Comment: @Hobbes I hardcoded the variable to "/var/www/appname/application/views/resources/Downloads" and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Hmm... If the path is correct, than it could possibly be a permissions issue.

Comment: If I do file_exists on $config['upload_path'] and it returns true.

Answer (score 1):

> Figured out the idiotic problem.
>
> I was autoloading the library and some how when I was trying to
>   initialize the configuration by $this->load->library('upload',
>   $config); it wouldn't do so.
>
> Instead I put my config files in config/upload.php
>
> The other method to do so would have been
>   $this->upload->initialize($config);

[See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664758/the-upload-path-does-not-appear-to-be-valid-codeigniter-file-upload-not-worki)

Answer (score -1):

Add this line

```
$this->CI->upload->initialize($config);
```

after

```
$this->CI->load->library('upload',$config);
```