# Where do I find the upload library?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm currently trying to get *CodeIgniter* file upload up and running using the [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html) however my library folder has no upload library, and I can't find anywhere to download it.

*Codeigniter* gives me a invalid file path error when attempting to upload, but shouldn't it also error out when trying to load the library? I'm a bit confused on both of those parts.

Comment: You'll find the `upload library` inside `system->libraries->Upload.php` where all the default `CI libraries` are saved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my upload path invalid? (Codeigniter-Library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080519/why-is-my-upload-path-invalid-codeigniter-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system->libraries->Upload.php`  You will find it there. And If you don't find this file then download the CodeIgniter again. Maybe you deleted it. To solve your invalid path error have a look at [why is my upload path invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080519/why-is-my-upload-path-invalid-codeigniter-library)