# Codeigniter AJAX file upload not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, file, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to upload a file to the same directory in which application folder is present

-application

-images

-system

-others...

The code that I am trying is

```
$config = array(
        'upload_path' => "images",
        'allowed_types' => "*",
        'overwrite' => TRUE,
        'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
        'max_height' => "768",
        'max_width' => "1024",
    );
    if(isset($_FILES["image"]["name"])) {
        if (0 < $_FILES['image']['error']) {
            echo 'Error Occurred During Upload Of File ' . $_FILES['image']['error'];
        } else {
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if(!$this->upload->do_upload('image')) { 
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();   //ALWAYS THIS LINE IS EXECUTING   
            }
            else {
                echo "FILE UPLOADED";
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please Select A File";
    }
```

The problem is that always the line having comment inside innermost if is executing and it says `<p>The upload path does not appear to be valid.</p>`.

When I tried to check whether that directory exists using is_dir, it also says that directory exists and also I tried giving it 777 file permission but still I am getting the same errors. I also tried most of the similar answers online but none worked.

Please HELP

Comment: Here is the clear example [click this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664758/the-upload-path-does-not-appear-to-be-valid-codeigniter-file-upload-not-worki)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664758/the-upload-path-does-not-appear-to-be-valid-codeigniter-file-upload-not-worki check the above link once.

Comment: after images in config put slash ex: 'images/'

Comment: ` echo var_dump(is_dir(base_url().'uploads/'));` is returning bool(false)

Comment: @sekaraja already tried that

Comment: @SuneelKumar that too not worked, already tried those things

Comment: @SowjanyaK ,not worked same error

Comment: load config seperatly first load upload library then $this->upload->initialize($config). then still u have same problem move your config into the config/upload.php

Comment: Shall I have to create a new file inside config folder with name upload.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$config = array(
        'upload_path' => "./images/",
        'allowed_types' => "*",
        'overwrite' => TRUE,
        'max_size' => "2048000",
        'max_height' => "768",
        'max_width' => "1024",
    );
```