# Codeigniter: The upload path does not appear to be valid. I get no errors in files array

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload

When i upload file it say that 'The upload path does not appear to be valid.'
`print_r($_FILES);` print the file info. What I am making wrong?

[Upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIJKu.png)

My directory tree is this [Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by9hR.png)

```
class Upload_pdf extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
}

public function do_upload_pdf()
{


    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf';
    $config['max_size']             = 100;
    $config['max_width']            = 1024;
    $config['max_height']           = 768;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}

}
print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664758/the-upload-path-does-not-appear-to-be-valid-codeigniter-file-upload-not-worki

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile tried these answers, but didn't work for me

Comment: try  $config['upload_path']          = '../uploads';. it should work fine.

Comment: try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41604500/2275490

Answer (score 2):

Here is your project directory tree

```
/erp-system
  /application
   -/config
   -/controllers
   -/cache
   -/core
  /system
  index.php
```

Just update the `$config['upload_path']` like this

If uploads folder inside the `application` folder

```
$config['upload_path'] = APPPATH.'uploads';
```

If outside the application folder

```
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'uploads';
```

`APPPATH` is the `application` folder of your project.

`FCPATH` is the project folder `erp-system`

Comment: My uploads directory is not in application folder

Comment: @ValentinGjorgoski according to your question your directory inside the application folder. So, the correct path is `APPPATH . 'uploads'`

Comment: Your uploads directory inside the application folder or outside?

Answer (score 0):

Autoload upload library in config/autoload file `$autoload['libraries'] = array("upload");`

```
   $config['upload_path']          = 'uploads/';
   $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf';
   $config['max_size']             = 100;
   $config['max_width']            = 1024;
   $config['max_height']           = 768;

        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
        {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
```

Comment: Does not make difference loading library it's working in both ways